# Servlet filter not working properly

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, servlet-filters

I am using spring mvc. To intercept the urls i'm using servlet filters in it. I am trying to authenticate user through "login.jsp". But when i enter the username and password and submit it.It again 
directs me to "login.jsp"

My Servlet Filter:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns={"/*"})
public class MyFilter implements Filter {


private ServletContext context;


public MyFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}


public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out  = response.getWriter();

    HttpServletRequest request1 = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    HttpServletResponse response1 = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    HttpSession session = request1.getSession(false);

    String uri = request1.getRequestURI();

    if( (session==null || session.getAttribute("users")==null)&& (!uri.endsWith("login.jsp") && !uri.endsWith("record/authenticate")) ){
            request1.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp").forward(request1, response1);
    }
    else{
        chain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}


public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
}

}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller

@RequestMapping("/record")
public class MainController {

@Resource(name="userService")
private UserService userService; 

@Resource(name="roleService")
private RoleService roleService;



@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public String GetFront(Model model){
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/authenticate",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String authenticate(@RequestParam("uname")String userName,@RequestParam("pass")String password,
        HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request,Model model){

    boolean success = userService.validate(userName,password);
    User user = userService.getuserByName(userName);
    Set<Role> roles = user.getRole();
    //String role = null;
    /*
    for (Role role1: roles) {           
        if(role1.getRoleName().equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){
            role = "admin";
        }           
    }
    */
    if(success){
        session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("users",userName);
        session.setAttribute("role", roles);
        return "Hello";
    }
    else{
        return "error";
    }

}
```

}

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Project1</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
<filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>Filter.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your session attribute in filter itself because every time you enter some input in login form and submit it to go on next page or servlet the session attribute for user is null . That's why its is looping on login page of yours .